# Confusion about including .c and .h files

Tags: c, include

Recently I have been working with the TIVA C series launchpad board which has a Cortex-M4 chip on it. I use the Code Composer Studio as my IDE.

There is a lot of confusion going on right now because through trial and error I see that in order to use certain functions that the chip manufacturer provides, I will need to include the .c file instead of including the .h file.

This caught me off guard and I admit that I am not an expert programmer or an expert when it comes to compiler design. But does anyone know why a compiler would need the .c file instead of needing the .h file?

The .h file is still being used since it has definitions in it that the .c file requires.

Perhaps a better question may be this:

When there is a .h file and a .c file, do you include the .c file in your code or do you include the .h file?

My trial and error exercise is telling me that you must include the .c file but I am totally in the blind on what the actual rules are.

Sorry if any part of this is too vague. I would be totally fine with sharing my main.c file so you can see how I included the files but I felt that my question is more of a question regarding what the general rules are for including files when there is both a .h and a .c file.

Thank you for any time you can give me in helping me understand this issue.

EDIT: Why the down votes? I thought coming here for help was what this place was about?

Comment: Are you sure you have to include .c file? Be careful for [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I think the problem might be you're not building or linking the c files.

Comment: The tooltip for the downvote button is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  I did not downvote, but I could believe that some around here would consider your question to exhibit a lack of research effort.

Comment: Thanks John. I think this was a hard problem to put into words. It was not simply about how .h and .c files work and my question was doing a poor job of getting the right question across. In a nutshell, I was trying to add .h files by saying #include "C:\ti\inc\<filename.h>" but for some reason the compiler inside Code Composer Studio was throwing a bunch of errors. If I instead said #include "C:\ti\inc\<filename.c>" then it worked. 

Anyways, I found that if I just tell Code Composer to manually add each .c and .h file one-by-one then it works. Still not sure why this failed the first way..

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand that substantially all C programs are built from multiple source files.  Under some circumstances many of those sources are pre-compiled into one or more libraries, but it is quite common that building a C program will involve also building multiple C source files and linking those to each other and to appropriate libraries to produce the final result.

It is also important to understand that although C permits multiple compatible *declarations* of functions and file-scope variables, it permits only one *definition* of each distinct function or variable anywhere in an entire program.  This is the primary reason for the convention of placing declarations into header files (ordinarily named with a `.h` extension).  Any number of source files that contribute to a given program may `#include` the same header file, but at most one of them could `#include` the source file that contains the corresponding definitions, and then only if that file were not included directly in the build.

It may be possible to write your main source file so that it `#include`s the `.c` files containing all the needed definitions directly, in which case it is not necessary to include the headers, but you cannot have two separate source files doing that contribute to the same program if that produces duplicate function definitions.  Ultimately, too, this approach may fail, for there can be limits on how large and complex a source file a given compiler can manage.

If there are header files accompanying the chip manufacturer's C source files, then your own  source files should include only those headers.  You should be able to build object files from such sources just fine.  To build executable programs, however, you must also build the chip manufacturer's C sources, and link them to your own.  It would be sensible to create a library containing the chip manufacturer's sources and to link that, but it would also work to build the needed source files directly for every program.  Your IDE should have support for both options.